# When I use the NSSet I get this Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, swift4.1

When I use the NSSet I get this Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)?

Here is my code:

```
var doneTask = NSSet()
let taskNum = course?.task?.count
let doneTask = course?.value(forKey: "length") as! NSSet
```

Comment: what type of value you are getting from the key "length"

Comment: Can you show me the data of course?

Answer (score -2):

fixed it with a condition statement to check for if the object is empty.
thank you anyways